# Removing duplicate row based on only one column in R

Tags: r, duplicates, unique

I have a dataframe in R with 1000+ rows. One of the columns is eventID and there are some duplicates. I want to delete rows so that all Event IDs are unique.

For example, if there are 3 rows with EVENT ID = 78, I want to delete 2 of them, but I do not care which 2.

I do not want to consider any of the other columns.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `duplicated` in `base R` to keep only the first row of the duplicate

```
subset(df1, !duplicated(EVENTID))
```

---

Or with `distinct` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
distinct(df1, EVENTID, .keep_all = TRUE)
```